# Need help understanding how the solution goes from one step to another $\int \frac{\sqrt{x+4}}{x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-fractions

This is the integral and the solution has the following steps outlined

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{x+4}}{x}dx$$

$$u=\sqrt{x+4}$$
$$u^2=x+4$$
$$2u\,du=dx$$

$$\int \frac{u}{u^2-4}(2u\,du)$$
$$\int \frac{2u^2}{u^2-4}\,du$$

I'm very comfortable with doing all of the above... no issues there, but the next step is where I get lost:

$$\int \left(2+ \frac{8}{u^2-4}\right) \, du$$

It's probably something very small I'm overlooking, but how did they get the term $2$ and $8$ in the numerator of the other term?

Comment: Long division.  $2$ is the quotient and $8$ is the remainder.

Comment: The Maple command $$Student[Calculus1]:-IntTutor(sqrt(x+4)/x, x) $$ does the job. See that [link](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=examples/Calculus1SingleStepping) for info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't it just because
$$
\frac{2 u^2}{u^2-4} = 2+\frac{8}{u^2-4} = \frac{2(u^2-4)+8}{u^2-4} ?
$$

Comment: Ohh... so its just a matter of substituting the variable $x$ and $u$ back in to get to the more simplified form?

Comment: Well the step you're uncomfortable with does not need going back to the variable x. Basically you just wrote the integrand in an algebraically equivalent form.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{2u^2}{u^2-4} = 2\left[ \frac{u^2}{u^2-4} \right] = 2\left[ \frac{u^2-4+4}{u^2-4} \right] = 2\left[ 1 + \frac{4}{u^2-4} \right] = 2 + \frac{8}{u^2-4}$$